# How the bit.ly system get the path from url?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP passing parameters via URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901635/php-passing-parameters-via-url)

I know that if you have a page `www.domain.com/?id=ABC` you can get the *ABC* in the `index.php` file using a

`$_GET['id'];`

My question is how does a `bit.ly/ABC` can give the *ABC* to their php file without having an `?id=ABC` in the path?

Comment: Why is your question tagged 'mysql' and 'JavaScript'? The question seems to PHP related only...

Comment: What makes you think they are using PHP? Their [jobs page](https://bitly.com/pages/jobs) is looking for people with Python experience.

Comment: Please note that while every answer (so far) is stating that they use mod_rewrite, that probably isn't true. mod_rewrite is one way to approach the problem, but not (in my experience) a common one in Python-land.

Comment: @Quentin = you're right, my mistake. Removed comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory they do actually have `?id=ABC` (or whatever their $_GET-parameter may be called), however it's being "hidden" via `mod_rewrite`.

A simple example of how their rewrite could be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)?$ index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

This would mean that `yourdomain.com/ANYTHINGhere123ThatsAnAlphaNumeric` would pass on the value after the slash to your `$_GET['id']`.

Hope this helps out!

Comment: Great - don't forget to "pick an answer" if you feel that your question has been resolved!

Answer (score 2):

`mod_rewrite` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

They are probably using an .htaccess to [rewrite the url](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) (mod_rewrite). Thus, there's a kind of internal conversion that change urls like `bit.ly/ABC` in `bit.ly/id=?ABC` (or something like this, I don't know the **real** name) and then they can retrieve the param. So,  assuming that they're using PHP (I don't know), they retrieve the param using `$_GET['id'];`

Comment: Isn't there a way the get the requested URL in PHP?

Comment: Yeah, I think it's the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. :-)

Comment: @TimBüthe What url? The url hidden by the bit.ly url?

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: No, the question is 'how to get that last part of the URL' and your answer is 'you have to rewrite it, to access it as an get parameter'. I have no experience in PHP, but in Java you could access the requested URL quite easy and extract the information without rewriting it.

Comment: @ninetwozero: You should provide this as an answer!