# How to get current page's isset

Tags: php, mysqli, isset

Firstly, I havent been able to find anything useful on the subject, anywhere really.
I'm trying to make something somewhat simular to a forum,

A small explanation, 
(And yes, I know its not seo, but I'm only looking for functionality atm.)
Lets say you go to example.com/?1, Then the database entry with the ID of 1 would be displayed on the index page, If you go to example.com/?3 then the DB entry with the ID of 3 would be displayed, etc..

```
DB Structure
----------------------------------------
| id | label | description | parent_id |
|---------------------------------------
| 1 | General | NULL       |         0 |
| 2 | Public  | NULL       |         1 |
| 3 | Private | NULL       |         1 |
----------------------------------------

PHP Code
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, label, description, parent_id FROM categories")) {
$stmt->execute(); // Execute the query.
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $label, $desc, $parent); // Get variables from result.
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        if(isset($id)) {

                echo "Hello, This is the $label category";

        }
    }
}
```

**What i'm missing is a way to get the users current "isset" (.com/?10, .com/?5, ETC) *Before* the query is run so i can check for that isset in the DB and get the correct values, right now it's outputting all rows in the DB, I would highly appreciate any help with it :)**

If you know of a better way of doing something like this(without using a framework), please let me know!

Comment: `while ($stmt->fetch()) {` not `while ($stmt2->fetch()) {` btw.

Comment: woops yeah, thanks for pointing it out, forgot to change it in the question :)

Answer (score 1):

From a terminology standpoint, it sounds like you are interested in understand what **parameters** are passed in the request's query string.

In your case, you are doing something a little weird in that be having URI format like `/?*` where `*` is integer ID value, you would actually be passing a variably named parameter.  Since you don't know what the parameter name is, you would have to do something like

```
$ids_in_query_string = array_keys($_GET);
```

To store the key names which infer which ID(s) were requested.

What I would suggest is to form your query string like `/?id=*`, that way you always know which key in `$_GET` to check against.  For example:

```
$id = null;
if (!empty($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
   $id = $_GET['id'];
}
if (!is_null($id)) {
    // perform your query for selected ID
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Not quite what i was looking for but you did help me find exactly what i can use with the word parameters which i had forgotten all about :) this is what i found if anything else is looking for something simular: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3901688/2267175
Cheers

Comment: @user2267175 OK.  You wanted URL rewriting.  had you left out the `?` in your sample URI's that probably would have been more clear :)