# Want to trim url and use them as parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I am using this as a url:

```
http://localhost/easyappointments/info/vikram/45346346
```

My original path is `http://localhost/easyappointments/index.php` and rest `/info/vikram/45346346` want to use as parameter. I will use `explode()` from php.

When I use this url, it says object not found.

Comment: I really don't think the question is that bad at all. It's entirely clear what his objective is.

Comment: I would check out this post: http://forum.codecall.net/topic/74170-clean-urls-with-php/ I think it will help you along.

Comment: The above post is awsome. I will implement and will check it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use them as parameters then you could pass them as parameters in the url.

```
http://localhost/easyappointments/index.php?word_param=vikram&num_param=45346346
```

Or this answer shows you how to do it the way you're trying to do it

[PHP passing parameters via URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901635/php-passing-parameters-via-url)